# How to make embedded Google documents display custom font correctly

Tags: google-sheets, fonts, custom-font

I have an embedded document that uses Google font called 'Tinos'. Everything shows fine, until a spreadsheet is embedded into a website. The spreadsheet, in turn, has Tinos font for text.

Tinos becomes an unrecognized font and reverts back to default, Arial.

I have recreated the issue here - http://2vsk.liepaja.edu.lv/Font_test.php.

The embed code is as follows.

I have used link href in the head section, font-face and @import methods, both separately and at the same time, and none did the magic.

```
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tinos" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head>

<style> 
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tinos');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
family=Dancing+Script:400,700');

@font-face {
font-family: "Tinos", sans-serif;
src: url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tinos');
}

body, html,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p  {
font-family: 'Tinos', serif;
font-size:16pt;
}
</style>

//embed code
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQYREv-4DJb5QJGvIAlZlPbl6hUlRrV-xULTTbHhlWhu3VjFgoquBV9AUEA0YSw1iCNI9AUpSBC-ADH/pubhtml?widget=true&amp;headers=false"></iframe>
```

Comment: Your link is returning a 404 (Page not found) error.

Comment: Hi. Did you ever get this working. I have a similar issue